# Determine return type of CompiledFunction expression

Tags: compile, data-types

Is there a way to extract the types of the arguments and the return type from a CompiledFunction expression? I am writing a package for code generation (basically a wrapper around CCodeGenerate) where the user supplies CompiledFunction expressions, and it would be nice if I could extract argument and return types directly from these expressions. (Otherwise the user has to specify them correctly, and that's a source of errors.)

Comment: When cf = Compile[...]; you can get the types of the arguments with cf[[2]]. The index 2 can be determined by inspecting FullForm[cf] and might be version dependent, so be sure to check carefully.

Answer (score 8):

The argument pattern can be read directly from the `CompiledFunction` expression as [DaveStrider](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/19476/davestrider) commented:

```
cf = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Integer}}, Round[x/y]];

cf[[2]]
```

> ```
> {_Real, _Integer}
> ```

The result information is printed by the CompiledFunctionTools package command `CompilePrint`:

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]

CompilePrint[cf]
```

> ```
>       2 arguments
>       2 Integer registers
>       3 Real registers
>       Underflow checking off
>       Overflow checking off
>       Integer overflow checking on
>       RuntimeAttributes -> {}
>
>       R0 = A1
>       I0 = A2
>       Result = I1
>
> 1 R1 = I0
> 2 R2 = Reciprocal[ R1]
> 3 R1 = R0 * R2
> 4 I1 = Round[ R1]
> 5 Return
> ```

Note that **A1** and **A2** are the arguments, assigned to Real and Integer registers respectively.  The output is an Integer (**I1**).  This information can be more directly read from `ToCompiledProcedure`:

```
ToCompiledProcedure[cf][[4]]
```

> ```
> CompiledResult[Register[Integer, 1]]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This tackles both argument types and the result type, as needed when dealing with generating and subsequently load function libraries etc.

```
argumentTypes[Verbatim[CompiledFunction][_, types_List, __]] := types

resultType[cf_CompiledFunction] := 
 resultType[ToCompiledProcedure[cf]]
resultType[CompiledProcedure[___, cr_CompiledResult, ___]] := 
  resultType[cr];
resultType[CompiledResult[Register[type_, _]]] := resultType[type];
resultType[MTensor[type_, rank_]] := {resultType[type], rank}
resultType[Integer] := _Integer
resultType[Real] := _Real
resultType[Complex] := _Complex
resultType[Boolean] := True | False
resultType[___] := $Failed
```